# How to gather columns and one paired column?

Tags: r, tidyr

First time here. Hope you can help. Please let me know for any improvements in reprex.

This is a gather() problem.

**Data**

```
structure(list(record_id = 110001L, choice_preindex = 0L, start_preindex = structure(16622, class = "Date"), 
    stop_preindex = structure(16631, class = "Date"), change_yn = 1L, 
    choice_index = 3L, start_index = structure(16632, class = "Date"), 
    stop_index = structure(17354, class = "Date"), final_choice = 1L, 
    reason_change = 1L), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Textual explanation**

I have interviewed persons and collected data on

- which product did he/she use prior to the meeting, and from when till when (choice_preindex, start_preindex, stop_preindex)
- which product did he/she use after the meeting, and from when till when (choice_index, start_index, stop_index)
- Did they switch after the meeting, if so why? (change_yn, reason_change)
- Was this the last change? (final_choice) *not important for now*

**Question**
I want to go from wide to long. However, I only want the data on whether they changed or not, and the reason for it added to the "index" row, and not the "pre-index" row. It should look like this:

```
| record_id | choice | start      | stop       | change_yn | reason_change | final choice |
|-----------|--------|------------|------------|-----------|---------------|--------------|
| 110001    | 0      | 2015-07-06 | 2015-07-15 | N/A       | N/A           | N/A          |
| 110001    | 3      | 2015-07-16 | 2017-07-07 | 1         | 1             | 1            |
```

Hope you can help

BW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data in long format with `pivot_longer` and use the pattern in the column names to get data in separate columns so that values of `choice_preindex` and `choice_index` are in 1-column, value of `start_preindex` and `start_index` are in one column and so on. For each `record_id` you can then `replace` the 1st value of `change_yn`, `final_choice` and `reason_change` column to `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = ends_with('index'), 
                      names_to = '.value', 
                      names_pattern = '(.*)_.*') %>%
  group_by(record_id) %>%
  mutate(across(c(change_yn, final_choice, reason_change), replace, 1, NA))

#    record_id change_yn final_choice reason_change choice start      stop      
#      <int>     <int>        <int>         <int>  <int> <date>     <date>    
#1    110001        NA           NA            NA      0 2015-07-06 2015-07-15
#2    110001         1            1             1      3 2015-07-16 2017-07-07
```

Comment: Dear Ronak. Amazingly quick, however, i received this error:

New names:
* .value -> .value...2
* .value -> .value...3
Error: `spec` must have `.name` and `.value` columns

Comment: Are you trying this on the data shared in your post Or using it on some other data? If you are using it on different data do they have same column names?

Comment: on the data i just posted.

Comment: That's strange. I just restarted R and checked again and I don't receive any error on that. What is your packageversion? I have `packageVersion('tidyr') #[1] ‘1.1.2’` and `packageVersion('dplyr') [1] ‘1.0.2’`. Probably you need to update the packages.

Comment: Ronak. Thank you very much for answering my first question. You were right, my R packages were really old. It works!. Although I still need to digest and understand what you have written. I will try this now on the large dataset. Will check your profile for future reference. KB